# Socket program gives "Transport endpoint is already connected" error

Tags: c, sockets, unix, connect

I am trying to create a very simple client-server chat program, where two programs can communicate with each other. However, the accept function is giving me the error "invalid argument". I am pasting the code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{

struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
struct sockaddr_in otheraddr;
int sockid;
int bindid;
int recvsockid;
int clientlen;
int connectid;

char send_msg[100] = "Program 1", recv_msg[100];
int recvid, sendid;
int myport_id = 4550;
int otherport_id = 4560;

sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
//fcntl(sockid, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

if (sockid < 0)
{
    printf("\nCould not create socket");
}

bzero((char*)&myaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
myaddr.sin_port = htons(myport_id);

bzero((char*)&otheraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
otheraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
otheraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
otheraddr.sin_port = htons(otherport_id);


bindid = bind(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if(bindid < 0)
    printf("bind error \n");

listen(bindid, 5);

do
{
    connectid = connect(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&otheraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if (connectid < 0 && !(errno == EINPROGRESS))
{
    //printf("%s", strerror(errno));
    perror("connect");
    exit(1);
}
    recvsockid = accept(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, &clientlen);
if (recvsockid < 0 && !(errno == EINPROGRESS || errno == EAGAIN))
{
    perror("accept");
    exit(1);
}
} while (connectid < 0 && recvsockid < 0);

do
{
    gets(send_msg);
    sendid = sendto(sockid, send_msg, 100, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&otheraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    fprintf(stderr, "%d", sendid);
    if(sendid < 0)
        printf("error3\n");

    recvid = recvfrom(recvsockid, recv_msg, 100, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, &clientlen);
    if (recvid < 0)
    {
        printf("\nError in receive");
        break;
    }

} while (1);

return 0;
}
```

I will be grateful if someone could tell me why I am getting this error, and how to correct it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to connect and to listen on the same socket `sockid`. I'm pretty sure you meant `bindid` for listening.

#### Edit 0:

Since you are creating both sides of the TCP connection in the same program, you need **two** socket descriptors, i.e. two calls to `socket(2)` in the setup code, one for connecting and one for accepting client connections.

Comment: I have corrected the mistake. However, I am now getting an error message "Invalid argument" from the accept function.

Answer (score 1):

```
recvsockid = accept(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, &clientlen);
```

You have not initialized `clientlen`, if you look at the documentation for accept():

> address_len
>                 Points to a socklen_t structure which on input specifies the length of the supplied sockaddr structure, and on output specifies
>   the length of the stored address.

So, set it to the length of `myaddr` prior to calling accept():

```
client_len = sizeof myaddr;
recvsockid = accept(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, &clientlen);
```