# Reconnecting with connect() on restarted server returns -Transport endpoint is already connected

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Okay, I've read this post in search for the right answer, but it does not seem to serve my purpose.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873650/socket-program-gives-transport-endpoint-is-already-connected-error?rq=1)

Now, getting to the trouble:

I have a conventional client-server architecture in C (all sockets are non-blocking), where the server is listening for incoming connections and the client tries to connect. The first connect succeeds and everything goes on just fine until I press Ctrl + C on my server.

The client side of the code detects that the connection is lost and arms a retry timer.
The client code is supposed to try a reconnect on the server again and again by using the POSIX interval timers on each timer popping. It however, does not close the socket or start out afresh. Now, every time it retries the connection, the connect() returns

> Transport endpoint is already connected

Even after restarting the server, which uses the SO_REUSEADDR and successfully starts, the connect does not complete. 
One thing that I will need to implement is the signal handler on the server for the shutdown on Ctrl+C.

But still, do I need to close the socket descriptor on the client side and start afresh every time a disconnect happens, or is there a way out of this?

Comment: You can't reconnect a TCP socket. You have to close it and create a new one.

Answer (score 5):

sockets cannot be reused.

Once the connection a socket served has gone down in both directions, the socket is unusable.

`close()` the client socket on loss of connection and create a new socket for a new connection.

---

**Update** (based on the comments below):

In the OP's case one side (the server side) went down (by means of the server process ending). This implies all sockets held by this process are implicitly `close()`ed and therefore `shutdown()` in both directions.

Comment: "socket served has gone down in both directions", what if only one side has gone down?

Comment: @Anshul: It's not about which **side** is `shutdown()` (goes down) but, as I wrote, about which **direction** is `shutdown()`. Sockets are full-duplex, will say work in both directions independently. This means even if the server shuts down the socket for reading it still could write data to the client and verse vica. However this does not apply to the case you are descibing, as your question states the server process is ended which means any socket held open by the server process is implicilty `close()`ed and with this implciticlty `shutdown()` in **both directions**.

Comment: @Anshul: Please note the difference between calls to `shutdown()` and `close()`. You might like to the relevant man pages.

Comment: `shutdown()` isn't what he's asking about. He's asking about the case where one *peer* has gone down. The answer to that is that if either peer goes down, the connection is down.