# Python Socket reconnect after connection failure

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am using python sockets to control something over a wireless IP connection. It is important to automatically re-establish the connection after a pipe failure, which often happens when the device hits wireless dead zones.

First, I setup a simple socket connection between the client, and server using a python program on each end. To verify there is a connection, I send a quick message from the client to the server.

If the socket handshake fails, I will catch it:

```
try:
    s.send(MESSAGE)
except socket.error, e:
     s.connect((IP,PORT))
     #In reality, the s.connect wouldn't be right here
     #I would use Loops to continuously re-establish on a socket error.
     #I would also use the try command for s.connect.
```

However, I cannot reconnect using this method, because

```
socket.error: [Errno 106] Transport endpoint is already connected
```

Among this error, I also sometimes run into the error 98 that the address is already in use.

Is there any method to work around these errors or a different protocol recommended that has better "self-healing" characteristics on poor network connections?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reconnecting with connect() on restarted server returns -Transport endpoint is already connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910973/reconnecting-with-connect-on-restarted-server-returns-transport-endpoint-is-a), [How can I reconnect a socket after a broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486561/how-can-i-reconnect-a-socket-after-a-broken-pipe).

Comment: The links were useful, and it partially works with the close command but do not solve my problem when an Ethernet cable is unplugged and plugged in, I am unable to get my code to catch the errors, and it freezes. I will post more edits to this question later. Thank You

Comment: Detecting that a cable gets unplugged is a different problem and has nothing to do with the reconnect you describe here. And there are lots of questions here about detecting such kind of disconnects. In short: use TCP keepalive.